# What would be the traditional Hindu perspective of anti natalist ideas?

Tags: sin, birth

The ideas are, procreation is immoral because it adds to the sum of suffering in the world. By not procreating, one spares their unborn children of preventable suffering and misery. Are there any ancient Hindu philosophies that also reflect this idea?

Comment: No. *Advaita Vedanta* would say - there is no suffering. It is only the *ignorance* of true knowledge that causes suffering. If ignorance, suffering would happen, even if or without procreation or physical bodies, in different planes of existence.